# Node.js 10 require('...') from node_modules is terribly slow

Tags: node.js, ts-node

I'm using the latest Node.js LTS 10 on Windows 10 and macOS 10.14.3. When I import a library using the `require` like `const require = require('rollup');` it takes about 10 minutes or more to import a library. I started noticing the problem after adding some `async` functions into my code. Using ES `import` in `mjs` files has problems with `ts-node` package and modules resolution, maybe there are other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had an `ignore: []` in my `ts-node` options, which caused processing all `node_modules`. Narrowing down the packages using regular expression `ignore: ['/node_modules\/(?!package-name).*/']` fixed the issue.